# Union of [a, 1]x[0, a^2] where a∈[0, 1]?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

The question is rather simple. Find the following indexed union of this Cartesian product of intervals:

$$\bigcup_{x \in [0, 1]}[x,1] \times [0,x^2] = \,...? $$

How am I to do this?

I could say that all intervals  $[x, 1]$ with $x \in [0, 1]$ are contained in the interval with $x=0$, i.e., $[0, 1]$ - and that all intervals $[0, x^2]$ with $x \in [0, 1]$ are contained in the interval with $x=1$, i.e., $[0, 1]$, such that the aforementioned union equals a Cartesian product of these two "biggest" intervals, that is to say that:

$$\bigcup_{x \in [0, 1]}[x,1] \times [0,x^2] = [0, 1]\times [0,1] $$

But my *"proof"* seems very handwavy and unrigorous because I'm relying on it being somehow obvious that $[0, 1]$ contains all other intervals $[x,1]$ with $x \in [0,1]$. Yet, I don't see how I could somehow show this with the limited knowledge assumed in the book *(it's from section 1.8 of Richard Hammack's "Book of Proof", an introductory book on proof writing, and in section 1.8 we've only thus far encountered very elementary naive set theory)*.

Any help? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to help you to argue rigorously

1) To prove an equality between two sets $A$ and $B$, one often shows $A \subset B$ and then $B \subset A$.

2) To show an inclusion like $A \subset B$ between sets, you typically would say "Let $a \in A$'' and then try and prove that $a \in B$.

3) To work with a union of sets note that

$a \in \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma} A_{\gamma}$

*if and only if*

there exists $\gamma \in \Gamma$ such that $a \in A_{\gamma}$.